# How to acess a property under specific profile in Maven

Tags: maven

I have 2 pom files - ParentPOM and ChildPOM. I want to Access property1 in ParentPOM in ChildPOM. I know this can be done by making ParentPOM as the parent for ChildPOM and use ${property1}. But property1 is defined in 2 profiles - trunk and release and I always want to get the value of property1 defined in release. How do I do that? ie:- In the below example, I want the value should be 0.0.2 and not 0.0.1 when I Access property1 in ChildPOM.

Note:**I cannot modify ParentPOM**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>x.x.x</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>ParentPOM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>ParentPOM</name>   
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>trunk</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>        
        <property1>0.0.1</property1>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <properties>
                <property1>0.0.2</property1>
        </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>

<project>
    <modelVersion>x.x.x</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.temp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ParentPOM</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ChildPOM</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>ChildPOM</name>   
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>trunk</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>        
        <property1>x.x.x</property1>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <properties>
                <property1>y.y.y</property1>
        </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
            <version>${property1}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a property "releaseProperty1" in your parent pom. Use this property both for the definition of "property1" in the profile "release" and for your use cases in the child pom.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I cannot modify parent pom. I added that into the question.

Comment: If the parent pom is not under your control, you should be very careful with your approach. You are effectively trying to read something that is actively disabled, which is probably not what the owner of the parent pom intended. I also doubt that you can achieve what you want to achieve without dirty hacking.

Answer (score 0):

There is one cleanish solution, but it all depends on the why... why do you want this?
The solution is: removing the release-profile from child and execute Maven like this: `mvn <goal>  -Prelease,!trunk`, i.e enable release profile and disable trunk profile.
To confirm this solution, run `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=property1 -Prelease,!trunk`